# Hide current time using PlaybackOverlayFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv

I'm writing an app for AndroidTV to watch VOD videos and Live Streaming. At the moment, for player controllers, I'm using the PlaybackOverlayFragment and for VOD videos no problems. I have just a little problem hiding the current time during Live streams. Is there a way to hide the TextView? I've noticed that setting the "total time" to < 0 the `ViewHolder` in `PlaybackControlsPresenter` sets to `GONE` `mTotalTime` and `mProgressBar`. Is it possibile to do the same thing with `mCurrentTime` in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the view directly by its id `this.mCurrentTime = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(id.current_time);` and then set the visibility on it to `View.INVISIBLE`. You could do this in your `PlaybackOverlayFragment` in `onCreateView()` or `onStart()`. This is subject to breaking when you update the leanback library, but this gives you the most control with the fewest lines of code.

If you want to go down the rabbit hole: The controls row view is set in `PlaybackControlsRowPresenter` here: `mPlaybackControlsPresenter = new PlaybackControlsPresenter(R.layout.lb_playback_controls);`.

You could also override that layout file (which I believe is what the leanback team recommends) and customize your layout however you like (as long as the ids stay the same). Or you could also override the style for the current time text view:

```
<style name="Widget.Leanback.PlaybackControlsTimeStyle">
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Leanback.PlaybackControlsTime</item>
</style>
```

But this will affect both time styles (current and total).

Basically, if you want control over the stock leanback components, you'll need to override *something*. What you choose to override depends on how much you need to change.

Comment: thanks Kyle for your suggestions but I'm trying to follow your first solution, but the `TextView current_time` is null both in the `onCreateView()` and the `onStart()`. The best solution I have found until now is to get the view in the `onRowChanged(PlaybackControlsRow row)` callback but it creates a not suitable behaviour. For a second the current_time appears and become invisible as soon as the player starts. I should put the `current_time` state to `INVISIBLE` before the controller appears. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to hide both `current_time` and `total_time`? Or do you JUST want to hide `current_time`?

Comment: Yes, I should hide both. Hiding `total_time` is simple because it is done by Leanback if the value is < 0 but for `current_time` is not enough. With your suggestion I'm able to hide also the `current_time` but for a while it appears and disappears when `onRowChanged()` is called. My question now is: is it possible to hide `current_time` before the media controller appears?

Comment: Okay that makes things easier. You could probably achieve what you want by overriding the text color of the [`PlaybackControlsTime`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/882ee91503f28d1fd60ba939c5b37db6b9d4ad29/sdk/extras/android/support/v17/leanback/res/values/styles.xml#68) style. You can do this by adding in a new color in your `colors.xml` file called `lb_playback_controls_time_text_color`. Then set this color to `@android:color/transparent`.

And in `onRowChanged()`, you can set `mCurrentTime` to the TV and then from there you can toggle the color to white or transparent.

Comment: I finally resolved this issue thanks to your help! I set the color to `@android:color/transparent` and set it on the `onRowChanged()` to its original color used by Leanback. Thank you so much!